# How to change Racket expression to Float type following Optimization Coach suggestion?

Tags: optimization, racket

I am writing a small numeric program, using Typed Racket. I want to improve its performance, and installed the [Optimization Coach](http://docs.racket-lang.org/optimization-coach/) plugin in DrRacket. However, I am not able to follow its advice in the very first suggestion that it outputs.

The code is the following (you can see it in context [here in Github](https://github.com/logc/pidec/blob/master/bellard.rkt#L29-L31)):

```lisp
  (define:  : Positive-Integer 20)
  (define: base : Positive-Integer 10)
  (define: N : Integer (* (+ n ) (exact-floor (/ (log base) (log 2)))))
```

and the Optimization Coach output is the following:

[image: Optimization Coach suggestion]

This seems simple enough, right? `2` can be changed to `2.0` and this yields an optimization (a less red color on the line), but **it is `base` that I cannot touch** without getting a `TypeCheck error`.

Defining or casting `base` as `Float`

```lisp
  (define: base : Float 10.0)
  ;; or
  (log (cast base Float))
```

leads to:

```sh
❯ raco exe bellard.rkt
bellard.rkt:31:47: Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: Real
  given: Number
  in: (/ (log base) (log 2))
```

How can I perform this optimization? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit silly, but I found the answer to my question in the [paper that presents Optimization Coach](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/stamourv/papers/optimization-coaching.pdf), which I had read too hastily.

> Unbeknownst to the programmer, however, this code suffers
>   from a special case in Racket’s treatment of mixed-type
>   arithmetic. Integer-float multiplication produces a floating
>   point number, unless the integer is 0, in which case the result
>   is the integer 0. Thus the result of the above multiplication
>   is a floating-point number most of the time, but not always,
>   making floating-point specialization unsafe

I supposed this also applied to mixed-type **division**, and changed my code to:

```
(define: N : Integer (* (+ n ) (exact-floor (/ (log (exact->inexact base))
                                                (log 2.0)))))
```

The optimization is confirmed by the plugin with a green line.